# Difference between $q.resolve() vs deferred.resolve() - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I need to return a customized response in a promise, from an *$http* call, so I can chain further calls. I have two implementations available. Can someone explain the difference between two, and argue if one is better?

*In fooService.js*

**Implementation #1**

```
function foo() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return $http.get('some-http-url')
        .then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data.Data;
            // Some manipulation on data
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        });
}
```

**Implementation #2**

```
function foo() {
    return $http.get('some-http-url')
        .then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data.Data;
            // Some manipulation on data
            return $q.resolve(data);
        });
}
```

*And then in FooController.js*

```
fooService.foo().then(function(response) {
    // Do something
});
```

**P.S. Some links, that can give me a better understanding are welcome.**



**## **************UPDATE 4th October, 2017****************

If I modify my function foo() like this

**Implementation #1**

```
function foo() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(/*some condition*/) {
        deferred.resolve('data');
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    else {
        deferred.reject('error');
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

**Implementation #2**

```
function foo() {
    if(/*some condition*/)
        return $q.resolve('data');
    else
        return $q.reject('error');
}
```

Which is the preferred way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) here at all, because [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) already [returns a promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get). 
Just return data in `.then()` and it will be available for the next `.then()` in the chain:

```
function foo() {
    return $http.get('some-http-url')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data.Data;
        });
}
```

The way you are doing your implementation is called [*deferred antipattern*](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern), more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: But the main question was the difference between ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`$q.resolve(‍‍‍‍)` vs `deferred.resolve()`.

Comment: When there is a `$http` request, there is a `promise` and it can be returned. But if we had to write a function in such a way that if a request has already been sent and the data now exists it will return the `existing data`, in this case we will not have a promise. How can we return the result without making a `promise` so that we can use the `then` chain?